# Apollo Explorer not reflecting changes in source code

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I've been making some changes to my source code but I'm having trouble getting them to show up in Apollo Explorer Sandbox. For example, I've added some mutations and an additional Query to one of my Resolvers in the source code and they aren't showing up in Apollo Sandbox. Any ideas?

```
import { Arg, Ctx, Int, Mutation, Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql";
import { Post } from "src/entities/Post";
import { MyContext } from "src/types";
import { idText } from "typescript";

@Resolver()
export class PostResolver {
    @Query(() => [Post])
    posts(@Ctx() { em }: MyContext): Promise<Post[]> {
        return em.find(Post, {});
    }

    @Query(() => Post, { nullable: true })
    post(@Arg("id", () => Int) id: number, @Ctx() { em }: MyContext): Promise<Post | null> {
        return em.findOne(Post, { id  });
    }

    @Mutation(() => Post)
    async createPost(
        @Arg("title") title: string,
        @Ctx() { em }: MyContext
    ): Promise<Post> {
        const post = em.create(Post, {title});
        await em.persistAndFlush(post);
        return post;
    }

    @Mutation(() => Post, {nullable: true})
    async updatePost(
        @Arg("id") id: number,
        @Arg("title", () => String, { nullable: true }) title: string,
        @Ctx() { em }: MyContext
    ): Promise<Post | null> {
        const post = await em.findOne(Post, { id });
        if (!post) {
            return null;
        }
        if (typeof title !== 'undefined') {
            post.title = title;
            await em.persistAndFlush(post);
        }
        return post;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was simply a matter of the javascript code in the dist folder not being updated with the typescript code. Using yarn watch updated it and fixed the issue.